Fivem JS not updating UI
I'm having trouble getting my script to update the UI with Lua data. I've handled the JavaScript part to the best of my ability as I'm reacquainting myself with frontend development. My friend and I are collaborating on an RZ script—I've handled the frontend UI, and he's tackled the Lua. We're attempting to pass Lua data to the JavaScript for UI updates, but it seems like something's faulty. So i was able to do everything but trying to handle the data for the top 4 players which is not updating i setup console logs and I'm still confused.
enter image description here enter image description here
I tried many ways but still not work this is my current js
 function clearText(ids) {
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
        $('#' + id).text('');
    });
}

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    const type = event.data.type;
    const playerData = event.data.PlayerData;
    const zonedata = event.data.zonedata;
    

    updateUI(playerData, zonedata);
});

function updateUI(playerData, zonedata) {
    // Get UI elements
    const leaderElement = document.getElementById("leader");
    const leaderKillsElement = document.getElementById("leaderkills");
    const killStreakNameElement = document.getElementById("killstreakname");
    const killStreakNumberElement = document.getElementById("killstreaknumber");
    const rewardOnKillElement = document.getElementById("rewardonkill");
    const totalKillsElement = document.getElementById("totalkills");
    const killsElement = document.getElementById("kills");
    const deathsElement = document.getElementById("deaths");
    const top1NameElement = document.getElementById("top1name");
    const player1KillsElement = document.getElementById("player1kills"); 
    const top2NameElement = document.getElementById("top2name");
    const player2KillsElement = document.getElementById("player2kills"); 
    const top3NameElement = document.getElementById("top3name");
    const player3KillsElement = document.getElementById("player3kills");
    const top4NameElement = document.getElementById("top4name");
    const player4KillsElement = document.getElementById("player4kills");

    // Update UI elements based on received data


    if (zonedata) {
        
        leaderElement.textContent = zonedata && typeof zonedata.leader !== 'undefined' && zonedata.leader !== null ? zonedata.leader : '';
        leaderKillsElement.textContent = zonedata && typeof zonedata.leaderkills !== 'undefined' ? zonedata.leaderkills : '';
        killStreakNameElement.textContent = zonedata && typeof zonedata.killStreakName !== 'undefined' ? zonedata.killStreakName : '';
        killStreakNumberElement.textContent = zonedata && typeof zonedata.killStreakNumber !== 'undefined' ? zonedata.killStreakNumber : '';
        rewardOnKillElement.textContent = '$ ' + (zonedata && typeof zonedata.rewardOnKill !== 'undefined' ? zonedata.rewardOnKill : '');
        totalKillsElement.textContent = zonedata && typeof zonedata.totalKillsToWin !== 'undefined' ? zonedata.totalKillsToWin : '';
        
        // Update other UI elements from zonedata as needed
    }

    if (playerData) {
        killsElement.textContent = playerData && typeof playerData.kills !== 'undefined' ? playerData.kills : '';
        deathsElement.textContent = playerData && typeof playerData.deaths !== 'undefined' ? playerData.deaths : '';
        
        // Update other UI elements from playerData as needed
    }

    // Update top players if available
    console.log('Received top players:', zonedata?.topplayers);
    if (zonedata?.topplayers?.length >= 4) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            const nameElement = document.getElementById(`top${i}name`);
            const killsElement = document.getElementById(`player${i}kills`);
            if (zonedata.topplayers[i]) {
                nameElement.textContent = zonedata.topplayers[i].name || '';
                killsElement.textContent = zonedata.topplayers[i].kills || '';
            }
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        console.log('Message received:', event.data); // Log the received message
        console.log('Message data:', JSON.stringify(event.data)); // Log the received data as JSON string

        if (typeof event.data.zonedata !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('Type of zonedata:', typeof event.data.zonedata); // Log the type of zonedata

            // Check if zonedata is a string and parse it
            if (typeof event.data.zonedata === 'string') {
                console.log('zonedata is a string, parsing...');
                try {
                    const zonedata = JSON.parse(event.data.zonedata);
                    // Now zonedata is an object, you can proceed to use it
                    updateUI(event.data.playerData, zonedata);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error parsing zonedata:', error);
                }
            } else {
                
                updateUI(event.data.playerData, event.data.zonedata);
            }
        }

        if (event.data.type === 'updateUI') {
            console.log('Updating UI with data:', event.data); // Log the received data

            updateUI(event.data.message);

        } else if (event.data.type === 'showUI') {
            console.log('Showing UI');
            $(".container").fadeIn('fast');
        } else if (event.data.type === 'hideUI') {
            console.log('Hiding UI');
            $(".container").fadeOut('fast');
        } else {
            console.log('Unknown message type:', event.data.type);
        }
    });

`
and here is my server.lua
function SetupZoneData()
    for k,v in pairs(Config.RedZones) do
        ZoneData[k] = {
            routingbucket = v.routingbucket, 
            totalKillsToWin = Config.DeafultKillsToWin,
            Players = {},
            leader = 'None',
            killStreakName = 'None',
            killStreakNumber = 0,
            rewardOnKill = Config.KillRewardMoney,
            topplayers = {}
        }
    end

    print(json.encode(ZoneData))
end
SetupZoneData()

Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        -- Loop through each zone
        for zoneName, zoneData in pairs(ZoneData) do
            if ZoneData[zoneName].Players then
                -- Sort players by kills
                local sortedPlayers = {}
                for playerId, stats in pairs(ZoneData[zoneName].Players) do
                    table.insert(sortedPlayers, { playerId = stats.source, kills = stats.kills, deaths = stats.deaths, killstreak = stats.killstreak, zonename = stats.zonename })
                end
 
                table.sort(sortedPlayers, function(a, b)
                    return a.kills > b.kills
                end)

                -- Update top 4 players in topplayers field
                local topPlayers = {}
                for i = 1, 4 do
                    if sortedPlayers[i] then
                        local playerId = sortedPlayers[i].playerId
                        local playerName = GetPlayerName(playerId)
                        local playerKills = sortedPlayers[i].kills
                        table.insert(topPlayers, { name = playerName, kills = playerKills })
                    end
                end
                
        
                print('Top Players for Zone ' .. zoneName .. ': ' .. json.encode(topPlayers))
                
                -- Find player with the highest kill streak
                local highestKillStreak = 0
                local playerWithHighestStreak = nil
                
                for _, player in ipairs(PlayerData) do
                    if player.killstreak > highestKillStreak then
                        highestKillStreak = player.killstreak
                        playerWithHighestStreak = player.source
                    end
                end
                 -- Set ZoneData with highest kill streak player
                 if playerWithHighestStreak then
                     ZoneData[zoneName].killStreakName = GetPlayerName(playerWithHighestStreak)
                     ZoneData[zoneName].killStreakNumber = highestKillStreak
                 else
                     ZoneData[zoneName].killStreakName = 'None'
                     ZoneData[zoneName].killStreakNumber = 0
                 end

                -- Update ZoneData with top players
                ZoneData[zoneName].topplayers = topPlayers
                print(json.encode(topPlayers))

                  -- Update clients with the latest player and zone data
                  for _, data in pairs(PlayerData) do
                    TriggerClientEvent('mtf-redzone:Client:RequestZoneSync', data.source, json.encode(ZoneData[zonename].Players[data.source]), json.encode(ZoneData[zoneName]))
                end
            end
        end

        -- Sleep for a minute before updating again (adjust as needed)
        Citizen.Wait(1000)
    end
end)


and here is the client.lua

local ActiveZones = {}
local InActiveZone = false
local display = false

function SetDisplay(bool)
    display = bool

    if bool then
        SendNUIMessage({
            type = "showUI",
            -- PlayerData = PlayerData,
            -- zonedata = zonedata,
            status = bool,
        })
    else
        SendNUIMessage({
            type = "hideUI",
            status = bool,
        })
    end
end

function UpdateUIThread(zonedata, playerData)
    while InActiveZone do
        Wait(500)
        SendNUIMessage({
            type = "updateUI",
            PlayerData = playerData,
            zonedata = zonedata,
          })
    end
end



-- [ Zone / Blip Creation ] --

Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    for k,v in pairs(Config.RedZones) do
       ActiveZones[k] = lib.zones.sphere({
        coords = v.coords,
        radius = v.zonesize,
        debug = Config.Debug,
        onEnter = function(self)
            TriggerServerEvent('mtf-redzone:Server:EnterZone', v.routingbucket, k)
            InActiveZone = true
            if Config.DisableInventory then exports.ox_inventory:weaponWheel(true) end
            GiveWeaponToPed(PlayerPedId(), v.issueweapon, 99999, false, true)
            SetDisplay(true)
        end,

        onExit = function(self)
            TriggerServerEvent('mtf-redzone:Server:LeftZone', v.routingbucket, k)
            RemoveAllPedWeapons(PlayerPedId())
          --  RemoveWeaponFromPed(PlayerPedId(), v.issueweapon)
            InActiveZone = false
            if Config.DisableInventory then exports.ox_inventory:weaponWheel(false)  end
            SetDisplay(false)
        end,
       })

        if Config.ShowZoneRadius then
            local radius = AddBlipForRadius(v.coords, v.blipradius)

            SetBlipSprite(radius, 1)
            SetBlipColour(radius, 1)
            SetBlipAlpha(radius, 65)
         end
    end
end)

RegisterNetEvent('mtf-redzone:SetCurrentWeapon', function()
    SetCurrentPedWeapon(PlayerPedId(), GetHashKey('weapon_pistol'), true)
end)

RegisterNetEvent('mtf-redzone:Client:RequestZoneSync', function(playerData, zoneData)
    print('Received zone data:', json.encode(zoneData)) -- Check the received data
    print('Received player data:', json.encode(playerData)) -- Check the received data
    -- Further processing, if needed
    UpdateUIThread(zoneData, playerData) -- Pass the zone data to the UI update function
end)

RegisterNetEvent('mtf-redzone:client:DeathHandler', function(nearestPoint)
    local player = PlayerPedId()
    DoScreenFadeOut(1000)
    Wait(1000)

    SetEntityCoords(PlayerPedId(), nearestPoint.x, nearestPoint.y, nearestPoint.z)

    Wait(2500) -- Wait for the player to be teleported

    SetEntityMaxHealth(player, 200)
    SetEntityHealth(player, 200)
    ClearPedBloodDamage(player)
    SetPlayerSprint(PlayerId(), true)

    -- qb-ambulancejob specific events to revive player
    TriggerEvent('hospital:client:Revive')

    DoScreenFadeIn(1000)

end)

AddEventHandler('onResourceStop', function()
    -- for k,v in pairs(Config.RedZones) do
    --     RemoveBlip(k)
    --     lib.zones.remove(k)
    -- end

end)

and here is the html for the top 4 players that i waant updated with the lua data
    <h2>TOP 4</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="red-zone">
            <div class="red-card left-card">
                <span class="badge">1
                </span >
                <p id="top1name">Josh</p>
            </div>
            <div class="red-card right-card">
                <i class="icon skull-icon"></i>
                <span id="player1kills">30</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="red-zone">
            <div class="red-card left-card">
                <span class="badge">2
                </span>
                <p id="top2name">Vinny</p>
            </div>
            <div class="red-card right-card">
                <i class="icon skull-icon"></i>
                <span id="player2kills">10</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="red-zone">
            <div class="red-card left-card">
                <span class="badge">3
                </span>
                <p id="top3name">llyty</p>
            </div>
            <div class="red-card right-card">
                <i class="icon skull-icon"></i>
                <span id="player3kills">9</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="red-zone">
            <div class="red-card left-card">
                <span class="badge">4
                </span>
                <p id="top4name">Bob</p>
            </div>
            <div class="red-card right-card">
                <i class="icon skull-icon"></i>
                <span id="player4kills">5</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>

